# Не записывается полностью значение в переменную в Postman

Tags: postman, environment-variables

Получаю следующий ответ на запрос в Postman

```html
   {
    "id": 9223372000001087046,
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Cat"
    },
    "name": "Grumpy Cat",
    "photoUrls": [
        "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/948294484596375552/RyGNqDEM_400x400.jpg"
    ],
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Mixed breed"
        }
    ],
    "status": "available"
}
```

Далее хочу "id" из этого ответа записать в переменную окружения

Делаю это с помощью команды

```html
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.environment.set("petId", jsonData.id);
```

После выполнения команды в переменную "petId" записывается следующее значение "9223372000001087000" , т.е. набор цифр записывается верный, но вместо последних трех цифр записывается три нуля.

Подскажите, где допускаю ошибку и что сделать, чтобы число записывалось верно?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65260698/11695435

Comment: Спасибо! Изучила информацию по ссылке, разобралась и решила свою проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вдруг кому-то понадобится, то вот решение, которое помогло мне:

```js
var libraryLink = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kentkost/f2699eb1dd41e2eb6203f0d0c77a987e/raw/bffae74aa3827ea195c10cf83bce4d78017bdf2d/postman-bigint.js'

const _dummy = setInterval(() => {}, 300000);

function sendRequest(req) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pm.sendRequest(req, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            return resolve(res);
        })
    });
}

(async function main() {
    let result1 = await sendRequest(libraryLink);
    eval(result1.text());   
    
    let newObj = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    pm.environment.set("petId", newObj.id);
    clearInterval(_dummy)
})();
```